# MySQL CASE not working in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

This works fine. If I change the @unit_type variable. The correct unit type comes out in the calculation.

```
set @unit_type = 'kilometers';
set @lat = 50;
set @lon = 100;
set @lat2 = 51;
set @lon2 = 101;

select 
(CASE @unit_type 
    WHEN 'feet' THEN 20000000
    WHEN 'miles' THEN 3696.1
    WHEN 'meters' THEN 6979100
    WHEN 'kilometers' THEN 6979
    END
* acos( cos( radians(@lat) ) 
    * cos( radians( @lat2 ) ) 
    * cos( radians( @lon2 ) 
    - radians(@lon) ) 
    + sin( radians(@lat) ) 
    * sin( radians( @lat2 ) ) 
) ) AS distance;
```

This however, does not. When I try to run this stored procedure, it will return in kilometers every time. And if I delete the case for kilometers, the result is null.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `anotherTest`(IN `lat` BIGINT, IN `lon` BIGINT, IN `lat2` BIGINT, IN `lon2` BIGINT, IN `unit_type` TEXT)
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    BEGIN

    select 
    (CASE @unit_type 
        WHEN 'feet' THEN 20000000
        WHEN 'miles' THEN 3696.1
        WHEN 'meters' THEN 6979100
        WHEN 'kilometers' THEN 6979
        END
    * acos( cos( radians(@lat) ) 
        * cos( radians( @lat2 ) ) 
        * cos( radians( @lon2 ) 
        - radians(@lon) ) 
        + sin( radians(@lat) ) 
        * sin( radians( @lat2 ) ) 
    ) ) AS distance;
    END
```

I just want to understand why this is, and how this would be better written to get around this issue.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**

The solution was to remove the @'s from within the SELECT statement of my procedure. As they are not required to access the parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `anotherTest`(IN `lat` BIGINT, IN `lon` BIGINT, IN `lat2` BIGINT, IN `lon2` BIGINT, IN `unit_type` TEXT)
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    BEGIN

    select 
    (CASE unit_type 
        WHEN 'feet' THEN 20000000
        WHEN 'miles' THEN 3696.1
        WHEN 'meters' THEN 6979100
        WHEN 'kilometers' THEN 6979
        END
    * acos( cos( radians(lat) ) 
        * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) 
        * cos( radians( lon2 ) 
        - radians(lon) ) 
        + sin( radians(lat) ) 
        * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) 
    ) ) AS distance;
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@unit_type` is a user variable. We don't see anywhere that is being set, in the procedure. (It may be set in the session preceding the call; it will have whatever value was last assigned to it in the session.)

We see the parameter passed in to the procedure is named `unit_type`. But we don't see any reference to that in the procedure.

One quick fix would be to set `@unit_type` user variable, immediately prior to the SELECT, to the value from the parameter:

```
SET @unit_type = unit_type;
```

The same issue exists for all the parameters as well, there's no reference to them either.

---

The other option to fix this would be to reference the procedure arguments in the SQL, replacing the references to the user_variables. (Looks like the quick edit there would be just to remove the `@` characters.)

---

There's a significant difference between **user-defined** variables and **procedure** variables.

[User-defined variables http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Turns out, based on what you told me here, all I had to do was remove the @'s from the parameters I was attempting to call from within my statement.